# Layer Recurrent Neural Network - Matlab design

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows, node-connections

I'm new to the Tikz package and I'm trying to get a better understanding of it by looking at several examples. However, I have not been able to reproduce the following diagram, as it is presented on the MathWorks website:

[image]

If you can pinpoint me the basic building blocks to obtain the final result it will be of great help! :)